# jOOQ - multiple bindings

Tags: java, sql, binding, jooq

I have a map of binding values:

```
final Map<String, Object> values = ...;
```

Before executing the query, I loop through the binding parameters and bind its value as following:

```
final ResultQuery<Record> q = ...;

for (final Param p : q.getParams().values()) {
    if (p.getParamName() != null) {
        q.bind(p.getParamName(), values.get(p.getParamName()));
    }
}
```

When the same binding is used multiple times, this seems to fail:

```
final ResultQuery<Record> q = create.select().from(DSL.table("my_table"))
        .where((DSL.field("identifier").eq(DSL.param("binding"))
                .and(DSL.field("identifier").eq(DSL.param("binding")))));

... code above ...

create.fetch(q);
```

In the generated query, only one of the bindings is filled in. The other is `null`.

Is there an alternative approach? The same binding parameter can only be used once, or is this a bug?

(I know this query doesn't make much sense, it is only for demonstrating the problem.)

The issue was probably solved if we could do the following instead, but it is not possible since `getParams()` returns `Param<?>` and not `Param<Object>`:

```
for (final Param p : q.getParams().values()) {
    if (p.getParamName() != null) {
        p.bind(values.get(p.getParamName()));
    }
}
```

**update** - The statement above is incorrect, since `getParams()` returns a `Map<String, Param>` and not `Map<String, Collection<Param>>`. It still woud be useful to bind a `Param` directly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in jOOQ 3.5.2 ([#4056](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4056)).

Another workaround apart from the one you've found would be to make sure that both instances of `"binding"` are in fact the same, you should probably externalise the bind value:

```
Param<Object> binding = DSL.param("binding");

final ResultQuery<Record> q = create.select().from(DSL.table("my_table"))
    .where((DSL.field("identifier").eq(binding)
            .and(DSL.field("identifier").eq(binding))));
```

Now, you'll explicitly create a single bind value that is used two times in the AST.